# error login enviando datos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

intento hacer un login sencillito en php pero cuando paso los datos del login al validador me da error que no encuentra con datos, llevo varias horas probando todo el rato pero no me lo pasa

login(index.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
<body>
   <form action="php/login.php" method="POST" >
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td><label>Usuario</label></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="a" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><label>Password</label></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="s" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>

</html>
```

validador (login.php)

```
<?php
require 'a/../../conect/bbddcasa.php'
// require 'a/../../conect/bdlogin.php'
?>

<?php
$u = $_POST['a'];
$c = $_POST['s'];
$nr=0;

$query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usr = '".$u."' and psw = '".$c."'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($nr != 0)
{
    //header("Location: pagina.html")
    echo "Bienvenido:" .$u;

}
else if ($nr == 0) 
{
    //header("Location: login.html");
    //echo "No ingreso"; 
    echo "<script> alert('Error');window.location= '../login.html' </script>";
}
?>
```

he intentado de todo, nombres de variables, nombres valores imput, post y get. no se me ocurre nada, muchas gracias de antemano

error en navegador: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

version de php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

servidor es gracias a una extension en vscode llamada five server (pasa lo mismo con phpserver y xampp)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hice unas pruebas en local y funciona perfecto. Si pudes poner la estructura de ubicación de los archivos. Pensé que podía ser el `2°` que tienes en el nombre de un directorio, pero en mi caso funciona aún con eso. Sin embargo, sugiero cambiarlo a `2do` u otro nombre, ya que `°` es un caracter especial y pudiera no ser parseado correctamente en la URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probado tu código y a mi me funciona perfectamente pero le he hecho unos cambios que te los pongo a continuación:

En el form tienes **php/login.php** espero sepas que esa carpeta php debe existir. Yo lo hice todo en la misma carpeta y quedó así:

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST" >
```

---

En login.php te comento los cambios con **===>**

```
<?php
/* ===> Comenté esta línea, seguro que haces tantos saltos atrás para acceder alas conexiones? */
//require 'a/../../conect/bbddcasa.php'
// require 'a/../../conect/bdlogin.php'

/* ===> Mejor me conecté en una línea.
Usted puede copiar a la carpeta del proyecto su conexión
ya que creo que de esos saltos a carpeta viene el error */
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','pruebas');
?>

/* ===> Porque abre y cierra php así por así?? */
<?php
$u = $_POST['a'];
$c = $_POST['s'];
$nr=0;

/* ===> Esto es opcional. Siempre verifique que es lo que viene de los forms */ 
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

$query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usr = '".$u."' and psw = '".$c."'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($nr != 0)
{
    //header("Location: pagina.html")
    echo "Bienvenido:" .$u;

}
else if ($nr == 0)
{
    //header("Location: login.html");
    //echo "No ingreso";
    echo "<script> alert('Error');window.location= '../login.html' </script>";
}
?>
```

El resultado queda así:

```
Array
(
    [a] => OCHOA
    [s] => 123456
)
Bienvenido: OCHOA
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, yo me volví loco y no encontré el fallo. era el maldito servidor xampp que estaba mal configurado el php y no estaba habilitado el mysqli no se porque si viene por defecto. el árbol de directorios estaba perfecto. 
muchísimas gracias por la ayuda